# Intermittent failures of a scheduled Spark Job on Databricks cluster after few runs

Tags: apache-spark, databricks, azure-databricks

Current Setup - Azure Data Factory pipeline scheduled to run every 15 mins, run some Databricks notebooks on an always on interactive databricks cluster.

Issue faced here is - This pipeline fails after 4-5 Runs. Due to issues at Spark Driver. There are no Collect statements which can cause driver memory to fill up.
Error logs show issue when Driver trying to write info to internal metastore ( which is automatically managed by Databricks). That thread causes GC Overhead limit breach and causes Full GC. As a result driver is killed and Notebook runs fail.

Here are the logs -

```
19/11/06 04:56:47 ERROR DatabricksMain$DBUncaughtExceptionHandler: Uncaught exception in thread db-atomic-read-worker-5095!
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
    at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:3332)
    at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.ensureCapacityInternal(AbstractStringBuilder.java:124)
    at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append(AbstractStringBuilder.java:596)
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:190)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.readUTFSpan(ObjectInputStream.java:3506)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.readUTFBody(ObjectInputStream.java:3414)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.readUTF(ObjectInputStream.java:3226)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readString(ObjectInputStream.java:1905)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1564)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:431)
    at java.util.Hashtable.readObject(Hashtable.java:1213)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor36.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1170)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2178)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2069)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1573)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:431)
    at org.apache.commons.lang3.SerializationUtils.clone(SerializationUtils.java:94)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anon$2.childValue(SparkContext.scala:370)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anon$2.childValue(SparkContext.scala:366)
    at java.lang.ThreadLocal$ThreadLocalMap.<init>(ThreadLocal.java:391)
    at java.lang.ThreadLocal$ThreadLocalMap.<init>(ThreadLocal.java:298)
    at java.lang.ThreadLocal.createInheritedMap(ThreadLocal.java:255)
    at java.lang.Thread.init(Thread.java:420)
    at java.lang.Thread.init(Thread.java:349)
    at java.lang.Thread.<init>(Thread.java:511)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl$NotifyHandshakeThread.<init>(SSLSocketImpl.java:2675)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1096)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1367)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1395)
19/11/06 04:56:47 ERROR DatabricksMain$DBUncaughtExceptionHandler: OutOfMemoryError in thread db-atomic-read-worker-5095! Killing thread now.
19/11/06 04:56:47 WARN TrapExitSecurityManager: Called "System.exit(15)" in db-atomic-read-worker-5095!
Stack Trace:
  java.lang.Thread.getStackTrace(Thread.java:1559)
  com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.TrapExitSecurityManager.checkExit(DriverLocal.scala:686)
  java.lang.Runtime.halt(Runtime.java:273)
  com.databricks.DatabricksMain$DBUncaughtExceptionHandler.uncaughtException(DatabricksMain.scala:363)
  java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:1057)
  java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:1052)
  java.lang.Thread.dispatchUncaughtException(Thread.java:1959)

19/11/06 04:56:47 WARN TrapExitSecurityManager: Allowed to exit because this is OOM!
19/11/06 04:56:52 INFO StaticConf$: DB_HOME: /databricks
19/11/06 04:56:53 INFO DriverDaemon$: ========== driver starting up ==========
19/11/06 04:56:53 INFO DriverDaemon$: Java: Private Build 1.8.0_222
19/11/06 04:56:53 INFO DriverDaemon$: OS: Linux/amd64 4.15.0-1050-azure
19/11/06 04:56:53 INFO DriverDaemon$: CWD: /databricks/driver
```

Connectivity issues with unmanaged  metastore -

```
urrent allocation: Map(1414820437514047686 -> 1, 289483405015881873 -> 175)
Ideal allocation: Map(1414820437514047686 -> 88, 289483405015881873 -> 88)
Starved pools: Map(1414820437514047686 -> 98.420017518)
19/11/06 04:55:37 INFO MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint: Asked to send map output locations for shuffle 588 to 10.139.64.20:49530
19/11/06 04:55:29 ERROR BoneCP: Failed to acquire connection to jdbc:mariadb://consolidated-westeurope-prod-metastore-addl-1.mysql.database.azure.com:3306/organization4787651615040525?trustServerCertificate=true&useSSL=true. Sleeping for 7000 ms. Attempts left: 5
java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not connect to consolidated-westeurope-prod-metastore-addl-1.mysql.database.azure.com:3306 : Connection reset
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.util.exceptions.ExceptionMapper.get(ExceptionMapper.java:161)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.util.exceptions.ExceptionMapper.getException(ExceptionMapper.java:106)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.protocol.AbstractConnectProtocol.connectWithoutProxy(AbstractConnectProtocol.java:1036)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.util.Utils.retrieveProxy(Utils.java:490)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.MariaDbConnection.newConnection(MariaDbConnection.java:144)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver.connect(Driver.java:90)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:208)
    at com.jolbox.bonecp.BoneCP.obtainRawInternalConnection(BoneCP.java:361)
    at com.jolbox.bonecp.BoneCP.obtainInternalConnection(BoneCP.java:269)
    at com.jolbox.bonecp.ConnectionHandle.<init>(ConnectionHandle.java:242)
    at com.jolbox.bonecp.PoolWatchThread.fillConnections(PoolWatchThread.java:115)
    at com.jolbox.bonecp.PoolWatchThread.run(PoolWatchThread.java:82)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not connect to consolidated-westeurope-prod-metastore-addl-1.mysql.database.azure.com:3306 : Connection reset
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.util.exceptions.ExceptionMapper.get(ExceptionMapper.java:161)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.util.exceptions.ExceptionMapper.connException(ExceptionMapper.java:79)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.protocol.AbstractConnectProtocol.handleConnectionPhases(AbstractConnectProtocol.java:724)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.protocol.AbstractConnectProtocol.connect(AbstractConnectProtocol.java:402)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.protocol.AbstractConnectProtocol.connectWithoutProxy(AbstractConnectProtocol.java:1032)
    ... 13 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:210)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(InputRecord.java:465)
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:503)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:975)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.waitForClose(SSLSocketImpl.java:1761)
    at sun.security.ssl.HandshakeOutStream.flush(HandshakeOutStream.java:124)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.kickstart(Handshaker.java:1079)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.kickstartHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1479)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1346)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1395)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1379)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.protocol.AbstractConnectProtocol.handleConnectionPhases(AbstractConnectProtocol.java:676)
    ... 15 more
19/11/06 04:55:37 WARN PreemptionMonitor: Preempted 43/43 tasks from 289483405015881873.
19/11/06 04:55:53 WARN PreemptionMonitor: Attempting to preempt 43 tasks from overallocated pools.
19/11/06 04:55:53 INFO PreemptionMonitor: Current allocation state: 
Current max parallelism: 176
```

I'd appreciate any answer to question -

## 1- Any spark job / databricks cluster parameter which I can tune up to avoid such Driver failures ?

## 2-How to avoid memory pileup by this daemon which is connected to Metastore. Flush memory after Job submission by causing some local GC.

## 3- Where can I see/control this unmanaged Metastore?

Comment: how did you setup
spark.driver.memoryOverhead ?

Comment: I haven't set it.. This setting is generally available with Yarn only.. and databricks cluster runs with standalone cluster manager

Comment: @ValaravausBlack  Did you find a solution for this issue. We are also facing the same, any help would be great. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I'm seeing the same issue on Databricks 10.4 LTS. Job runs fine on 9.1 LTS, but fails with java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded on 10.4 LTS. Issue appears to be on the driver, which is odd considering that we usually see very little activity on the driver. I am, of course, also not doing any collects. Did you guy find the root cause of this? Or a work-around maybe?

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered a similar issue. My issue is caused by the memory of the driver node is used up.

In my spark logging, There are full GC loggings before the error.

By the way, I am using Azure databricks.